# Connected Components in an undirected graph - Algorithm fhor StackOverflow users (Segmentation fault)

Tags: c, graph

In response to my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65045904/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph-c-language) on the subject, I [found (pg 89)](https://riptutorial.com/ebook/algorithm)/ built  an algorithm that prints the connected components. However, for an input of the type 
6 edges
4 vertices
2 3
2 3
4 5
0 1
the program returns a segmentation error. Why?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXVERTICES 100    

void enqueue(int);
int deque();
int isConnected(char **graph,int noOfVertices);
void BFS(char **graph,int vertex,int noOfVertices);    
int count = 0;

struct node{
    int v;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
typedef struct node *Nodeptr;

Nodeptr Qfront = NULL;
Nodeptr Qrear = NULL;
char *visited;//array that keeps track of visited vertices.

void enqueue(int vertex){
    if(Qfront == NULL){
        Qfront = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        Qfront->v = vertex;
        Qfront->next = NULL;
        Qrear = Qfront;
    }
    else{
        Nodeptr newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newNode->v = vertex;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        Qrear->next = newNode;
        Qrear = newNode;
    }
}

int deque(){
    if(Qfront == NULL){
        printf("Q is empty , returning -1\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        int v = Qfront->v;
        Nodeptr temp= Qfront;
        if(Qfront == Qrear){
            Qfront = Qfront->next;
            Qrear = NULL;
        }
        else
            Qfront = Qfront->next;
        free(temp);
        return v;
    }
}

int isConnected(char **graph,int noOfVertices){
    int i;
    BFS(graph,0,noOfVertices);
    for(i = 0;i < noOfVertices;++i)
        if(visited[i] == 'N')
         return 0;
    return 1;
}

void BFS(char **graph,int v,int noOfVertices){        
    int i,vertex;
    visited[v] = 'Y';
    enqueue(v);    
    while((vertex = deque()) != -1){
        //printf("\nConnected component %d\n",++count);
        //printf("%d ",vertex+1);            
        for(i = 0;i < noOfVertices;++i)
            if(graph[vertex][i] == 1 && visited[i] == 'N'){
                enqueue(i);
                visited[i] = 'Y';
            }
    }
}

void listConnectedComponents(char **graph,int noOfVertices){
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < noOfVertices;++i){
        if(visited[i] == 'N')
            BFS(graph,i,noOfVertices);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n,e;//n is number of vertices, e is number of edges.
    int i,j;
    char **graph;//adjacency matrix

    printf("Enter number of vertices:");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if(n < 0 || n > MAXVERTICES){
        fprintf(stderr, "Please enter a valid positive integer from 1 to %d",MAXVERTICES);
        return -1;
    }

    graph = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    visited = malloc(n*sizeof(char));

    for(i = 0;i < n;++i){
        graph[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        visited[i] = 'N';//initially all vertices are not visited.
        for(j = 0;j < n;++j)
            graph[i][j] = 0;
    }

    printf("enter number of edges and then enter them in pairs:");
    scanf("%d",&e);

    for(i = 0;i < e;++i){
        int u,v;
        scanf("%d%d",&u,&v);
        graph[u-1][v-1] = 1;
        graph[v-1][u-1] = 1;
    }    
    
    if(isConnected(graph,n))
        printf("The graph is connected");
    else printf("The graph is NOT connected\n");       
}
```

I believe it is due to the positions allocated in the adjacency matrix.

Comment: First decide u,v are 0 based on 1 based. Input is from 0, but you are adding at u-1,v-1

Comment: Please do a little bit of research what this "segmentation error" means. Just search for the error message and your progarmming language online. For a valida question here, you'd have to provide a [mcve], preferably with hard-coded values instead of manual input, to make it as easy to reproduce as possible. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].